# Lost KDE-Desktop, copy files to USB pen drive

Tags: linux, debian, file-copy, graphics

I lost KDE desktop trying to upgrade, I've been using Parrot OS (KDE Version) for over a year now, in dual boot with Windows 10. I started using Parrot OS to learn ethical haking, but with time I lost interest in haking, but still loved the parrot OS theme and graphics, so 3 days before today, I installed Parrot OS (I used 'Parrot-kde-security-4.6_amd64.iso' file) to be the only OS on my laptop and moved all my files into it. Then I tried to upgrade it using Sudo parrot-upgrade Which kept giving an error about a 'rolling version' and a 'public key'.

So I searched the web and found this to solve the 'public key' error, 'sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys # the PUBLIC KEY was here'

But it gave me a new error about a package, so I used this, 'sudo apt install gcc-8-base'

then I used the usual command, 'Sudo parrot-upgrade' Which gave me a new error, It was 3am in the night and I don't think I was in my best consciousness, I read the error and saw the command to remove unnecessary packages, Which I did indeed use (I know, I shouldn't be awake, this late...)-: , but then around 80% of the process completion, I saw the wifi connection disappear, and I couldn't access folders anymore, it was like a nightmare, I panicked and quickly switched off the laptop from power button. Then I switched it on again and it's only a small terminal on the top left corner of desktop. I tried these commands, 'Sudo apt-get install plasma-desktop' 'Sudo apt-get install plasma-workspace' 'Sudo apt-get update --fix-missing'

They don't work, I think there is no connection to the internet, even when I used a cable to connect with the router.

I tried to copy files from parrot to my pendrive, but then again, I can't see the pendrive listed in '/media'.

Now I'm hoping to go with this, "If you nuked Network Manager too (or it doesn't work) I think I would fall back to chrooting your install from within a LiveCD (with a working network connection).

Boot to the LiveCD (Select Try Ubuntu). Set up a network connection like you normally would.

Open a terminal and run sudo fdisk -l and note the /dev/sdX# name of your install's partition. In this example I assume /dev/sda1.

Mount it with sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt — If you have mounted it as something else (eg if you used Nautilus and it mounted as /media/ubuntu/...) you need to replace /mnt in the following two commands with its actual mount point.

Cross-mount various system things: for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done Chroot in: sudo chroot /mnt. You are now root on your old install.

Once you're connected, Just run: sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop"

I have a dozen valuable files in the hard drive and I need to get them out, I'm sure if I do get them out, I won't ever touch parrot OS again, somethings ask for whole another level of intelligence. Please help!